# HTML5 Video solution with showing images during playback

Tags: flash, html, html5-video

I'm searching a solution to play a HTML 5 Video and show different images (or similar) on various points (e.g. min 2:15) in the video.

Is this even possible or I should rather use Flash?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get something like this working a few weeks ago. The problem is that what you want to do boils down to on-the-fly video editing. In my application, I was inserting text screens between video segments to explain parts of the video. You might try chopping the video, and sequencing the display that way. Eventually, I settled on Flash. It was a lot cleaner.